# Is $q\to (p \vee \neg r)$ equivalent to $q \to p$?

Tags: first-order-logic

I am hesitating if the following is correct:

1. $q\to (p \vee \neg r)$ Assume this is a premise
2. Therefore $q \to (\neg r \vee p)$
3. Therefore $q \to (r \to p)$
4. Therefore $q \to p$ - if this is correct, by which axiom/rule?

Comment: What if $q$ is true, $p$ is false, and $\neg r$ is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not correct, because the inference from step 3 to step 4 does not follow.

If $q\to r$ and $r\to p$, then we have $q\to p$. But this is not the same as $q\to(r\to p)$.

As a concrete example, let $q$ be "It is raining", $r$ be "I do not bring my umbrella", and $p$ be "I get wet". If $q$ is true, then indeed $r\to p$ (if I leave my umbrella behind I will get wet), but it is not true that $q\to p$: it could rain without me getting wet (namely, if I remember my umbrella!).

This example suggests where the equivalence fails: if $q$ is true, $r$ is false, and $p$ is false. Indeed, you can check that the two expressions have different values in this case.